# How do I use Cross-validation to evaluate/validate different settings (“hyperparameters”) in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, hyperparameter

I've gone through a few posts about Cross-validation such as [post1](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/), [post2](https://towardsdatascience.com/cross-validation-in-machine-learning-72924a69872f), specially the [scikit-learn doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), which says

> When evaluating different settings (“hyperparameters”) for estimators, such as the C setting that must be manually set for an SVM, there is still a risk of overfitting on the test set because the parameters can be tweaked until the estimator performs optimally.

I am aware that CV could help solve the problem of lacking of data by using $k-1$ of the folds as training data and the remaining part as test data.

[image]

However, I don't see how does Cross-validation help to solve the problem of evaluating different settings.

Consider this code

```
>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
>>> scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)
>>> scores
array([0.96..., 1.  ..., 0.96..., 0.96..., 1.        ])
```

which is just one possible setting `C=1`, how about others, e.g. `C=0.5`

How do I use CV to evaluate/validate different settings?

```
>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.5)
>>> scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)
```

---

**Note:** I understand how does CV work within one setting, I would just like to know how it help to evaluate/validate different settings. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Assume  `k` to refers to the number of folds and I am comparing 10 different settings, from `C=0.1` to `C=1.0`. Each setting produces its own scores like `array([0.96..., 1.  ..., 0.96..., 0.96..., 1.        ])` with 'cv=5'. So, `k` is equal to 5, `n` is equal to 10, I would pick the best from all 10 averages, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, using some kind of hyper-parameter search, e.g. grid search, for each of the hyper-parameters, you'll train your model on $n-1$ folds, and test on the holdout fold, repeat this experiment $n$ times and typically report the average of the scores you have over these $n$ holdout folds. This way, you'll quantify how good you've done for each of the different hyper-parameter configurations and pick the best one to apply and report your final success on the test set.

Comment: Thank you.  Assume  `k` to refers to the number of folds and I am comparing 10 different settings, from `C=0.1` to `C=1.0`. Each setting produces its own scores like `array([0.96..., 1.  ..., 0.96..., 0.96..., 1.        ])` with 'cv=5'. So, `k` is equal to 5, `n` is equal to 10, I would pick the best from all 10 averages, right?

Comment: yes, that's correct @WXJ96163